# Social network friends matrix equation expression

Tags: matrices

We consider a collection of n people who participate in a social network in which pairs of people can be connected, by 'friending' each other. The n x n matrix F is the friend matrix, defined by $F_{ij} = 1$ if persons i and j are friends, and $F_{ij} = 0$ if not. We assume that the friend relationship is symmetric, i.e., person i and person ja are friends means person j and person i are  friends. We will also assume that $F_{ii} =0$

t is the n-vector with $t_i$ being the total number of friends of person i. Give an expression for in terms of matrix F. Briefly justify your expression

Comment: $t_i=\sum_{j\in N}F_{ij}$. 

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you explain that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the $I$th row of the matrix $F$: $(F_{i1}, F_{i2},\ldots, F_{in})$. Each of these elements $F_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$. Thus summing the elements of the $I$th row simply counts the number of 1s in that row. This is precisely the number of friends $I$ has.

Thus $t_i = \sum_{j\in N}F_{ij}$.

Comment: This is correct, but I think it is supposed to be written as a matrix-vector equation.

Comment: That would be $t=F\times \mathbf{1}_{n\times 1}$, where $\mathbf{1}_{n\times 1}$ is the  $n$-dimensional column vector of 1s.